# How to smoothly animate position & size of an rounded rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am implementing a "pane" view component. Similar to IntelliJ or VSCode, where each pane can be rearranged into different rows and columns. The drag-and-drop rearrange action requires a preview animation: a box that animates around the screen, showing where the new pane would be inserted if the action was finished.

Basically, I need an absolutely-positioned rounded rectangle that can smoothly animate around the screen. Ideally this would be GPU-accelerated.

My attempts:

**Attempt no. 1**

I simply created a `<div>` element and animated the `height`, `width`, `top` and `left` values. This works, and allows all other CSS effects to work on the rectangle, like borders and rounded edges. However, it's not very fast. Animating the position and size directly is recommended against because it forces a reflow on each frame.

**Attempt no. 2**

Instead, I created `1px by 1px` colored `<div>`, and set its size and position by editing it's `transform` CSS property. This is *super* smooth because it uses the GPU-accelerated transform property. However, it comes with a downside: I cannot style the `<div>`. I cannot use `border` or `border-radius`, otherwise they become distorted by the `scale` transformation.

**Ideas**

- Since a rectangle is a simple shape, could we generate an `svg` and interpolate between different positions? If this happens within the `viewBox`, would it be smooth? I'm unsure about this, because I don't have much experience with SVGs.

**My question** – how can I smoothly animate a div around the screen, which is styled with a `border` or `border-radius`?

I could live without the `border`, but the `border-radius` is strongly desired.

Comment: SInce smooth moving animation can be possible only with `transform`, `svg` couldn't implement smooth moving animation?

Comment: Making a `div` tag with `1px by 1px` can make smooth animation and seems making `border-radius` would be an issue. What if placing a rounded quarter border at each corner? Whenever changing `border-radius` value then each cornered border changes each `border-radius` value.

Comment: @jacobkim Yeah, that's what I thought :( it was just an idea, in case there was an SVG trick I didn't know about. I considering using a custom clipping image for each corner (I believe that's what you're suggesting) but then I would still have to animate the position of the rounded quarter border, which would be slow, since it couldn't use `transform`.

Comment: Could you include simple examples of your two attempts in your question so we can easily see where the time is going?

Comment: @haz Can not imagine how slow or how complicated when animating `div` with `1px by 1px` and sizing cornered `border-radius`! Just thought what if `div` with `1px by 1px` and with `border-radius: 50%` is used as lines for cornered border. Then the issue will be paths calculation for border radius value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fix! This allows smooth animations (using GPU-accelerated transformations) for a `<div/>` with rounded corners and a border, without any stretching.

It's based on the "border image" concept. Instead of animating one `<div/>`, we can animate 9 different divs, each representing a slice of the rectangle.

- Top left corner
- Top center rectangle
- Top right corner
- Middle left rectangle
- Middle center rectangle
- Middle right rectangle
- Bottom left corner
- Bottom center rectangle
- Bottom right corner

The corners don't need to be scaled, only translated. This prevents any stretching. The rectangle edges are scaled in line with the border, and so it doesn't stretch a `solid` border.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I have fully understood the problem as I am unable to recreate it in this situation:

This snippet uses transform scale and transform translate to animate an element. Evertyhing is calculated with vmin used as the basic unit just so you'll see the same aspect ratios whatever device/viewport you are using.

On my laptop the GPU usage is a pretty consistent 13%, the transforms are smooth and I can't see any distortion. So is there perhaps in the original code some absolutely defined unit used that doesn't for example scale correctly?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  --containerw: 80vmin;
  --containerh: 60vmin;
  width: var(--containerw);
  height: var(--containerh);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
}

.test {
  --startleft: 10;
  /* where it starts (within the container as a %) */
  --starttop: 10;
  --endleft: 70;
  /* where you want it to go to (within the container as a %) */
  --endtop: 70;
  --scalex: 4;
  /* how much you want it to grow */
  --scaley: 2;
  --w: 10%;
  /* its width */
  --h: 10%;
  /* its height */
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  border-width: 0.2vmin;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: cyan;
  animation: move 10s infinite linear;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translate(calc(var(--startleft) * var(--containerw) / 100), calc(var(--starttop) * var(--containerh) / 100));
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(var(--scalex), var(--scaley)) translate(calc(var(--endleft) * var(--containerw) / 100 / var(--scalex)), calc(var(--endtop) * var(--containerh) / 100 / var(--scaley)));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Compare the width of the border at the smallest size to the largest size - at `100%`, the border is noticeably thicker, and has different thickness on the bottom and top vs. the sides. The same occurs for the rounded corners, but it's a bit harder to see. Viewing on Chrome on OSX. The `scale` value stretches the element, rather than resizing it. This means that the border gets stretched, so if I define a `1px` border, when the scale increases, it might be `5px` (for example). This is what I'm trying to work around :(

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the border width to scale but you do want the height and width of the element to scale (possibly by different amounts?) In my snippet yes I scale the border too as the whole thing is scaled